# Remote control events in UITabBar to control play

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940201/receiving-remotecontrolevents-to-first-tab-when-interacting-in-second-tab-in-a-t). But I still can't quite figure out what to do.

So, I have a tabbar app that functions similar to an ipod. One view controller is the "NOW PLAYING" view controller and it is the view controller at index 1. So, in that VC I have:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Turn on remote control event delivery
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    // Set itself as the first responder
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Where is my event?");
    if(event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl)
    {
        switch (event.subtype) {
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                NSLog(@"Pause");
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
                NSLog(@"Next");
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
                NSLog(@"Prev");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"SOMETHING WAS CLICKED");
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

I don't receive any events on remote clicks either on the headphones or on the double-home button click shortcuts. I am running on an actual iPhone, not in the simulator. I am using a AVQueuePlayer (which IS playing) to manage my media.

Answer (score 0):

I just shoved everything into the AppDelegate and told the AppDelegate to call to the ViewController to tell it what to do and it worked fine. Is it poor practise to put it in the AppDelegate?